# How to install ubuntu in Intels i9 line of processors(7920 &7960)

Tags: system-installation, intel, i915

I recently purchased intels latest offering i9 core X-series 7960.While i got windows running on it but ubuntu 16.04,17.10.1 doesnt boot and also tried Fedora but of no use .I tried with acpi=off but that doesnt solve the problem either.

Help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: Any message? Did you try disable secure boot`

Comment: I am trying to capture the logs from the grub menu and i will post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling secure boot in the bios worked for me.  Was able to install.
But my wifi and network adaptors are not visible.

Comment: Disabling secure boot doesnt work either.